# Hiding URL parameters with .htaccess while still making them available to $_GET

Tags: .htaccess

I have a script on my site ('write-review.php') that takes an optional url parameter 'site'. So server-side requests could be:

```
/reviews/write-review.php
```

or

```
/reviews/write-review.php?site=foo
```

I'm using .htaccess to create search engine friendly URLs and hide my php extensions, so that requests to this script are respectively rewritten as

```
/reviews/write-a-review/
```

or

```
/reviews/write-a-review/foo
```

I think having 'foo' in the URL may cause confusion for my users, so I'm trying to **write an htaccess rewrite rule that removes 'foo' while still passing this variable to my script**. Thus, a request to /reviews/write-a-review/foo would be rewritten as /reviews/write-a-review/ but write-review.php would be passed 'foo'.

The rewrite rule I currently have in place is:

```
RewriteRule ^reviews/write-a-review/?$ reviews/write-review.php
RewriteRule ^reviews/write-a-review/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ reviews/write-review.php?site=$1
```

Is it even possible to do what I've described above? There are MANY questions on Stack Overflow that are similar to this, and I've read through at least a dozen, but I haven't found a way to do this specifically.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even possible to do what I've described above?

No. To alter the actual URL the user inputs, you'd have to do a header redirect, during which you would lose `foo`.

This is not possible, except maybe by using ridiculous technical tricks like storing `foo` in a session variable or something. I would not recommend going that route.

Comment: Thanks, Pekka. Guess I'll give up on this.